# как из boost::filter_iterator получить исходный итератор?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

```
std::vector<int> arr{1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 4, -1, 4, 4, 4, -1, 7, 8, -1};
auto begin = boost::make_filter_iterator<is_positive_number>(arr.begin(), arr.end());
auto end = boost::make_filter_iterator<is_positive_number>(arr.end(), arr.end());
auto lower = std::lower_bound(arr.begin(), arr.end(), i, [](const auto& val1, const auto& val2) {
        return val1 < val2;
    });
std::vector<int>::iterator iter = ??????(lower);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное в `std::lower_bound` надо было передавать `begin` и `end`, а то они не используются. А получить исходный итератор можно через `lower.base()`.